# Display options.xul programmatically

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have an xul overlay based Firefox Add-on that works.  It has inline options defined in content/options.xul and they display/function correctly when the user goes to Firefox->Add-ons->Extensions->{The Name of My Extension}->Options

The question, can I a create a button on my Add-on that will launch my options either by taking the user to Firefox->Add-ons->Extensions->{The Name of My Extension}->Options with one click or by launching a dialog based on options.xul?

Right now I am maintaining a separate options.html and options.js that gets and sets the same settings that options.xul handles when the user navigates there via the Firefox button but I would much rather dump options.html and options.js and only maintain my main.js and options.xul.

Any comments or code examples will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easiest to do via a global function `BrowserOpenAddonsMgr()` defined in the browser window, like this:

```js
BrowserOpenAddonsMgr("addons://detail/" + encodeURIComponent(addonID));
```

This function takes care of focusing the existing add-ons tab if there is one or opening a new tab. It will not scroll down to the options however which is an issue if the add-on has a lengthy description. Starting with Firefox 12 this can be solved by adding "/preferences" to the view identifier:

```js
BrowserOpenAddonsMgr("addons://detail/" + encodeURIComponent(addonID) + "/preferences");
```

With older Firefox versions you are out of luck (and you shouldn't use this suffix there, it won't work). The other issue is that there can be a lengthy "loading" phase where the add-ons manager fetches metadata for all extensions.

Comment: I'm having trouble using the `BrowserOpenAddonsMgr()` function. I can't find any documentation or other uses online. Can I use within main.js from the addon sdk?

Comment: @thefoyer: You cannot - it is a function defined in the context of the browser window. Meaning that you would first have to get the browser window with low-level modules and call the function then: `require("window-utils").activeBrowserWindow.BrowserOpenAddonsMgr(...)`. This function is an implementation detail so you won't find it documented anywhere other than the source code.

Comment: thanks! using the non-deprecated API, that’s in spaghetti code: `require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow().BrowserOpenAddonsMgr("addons://detail/" + encodeURIComponent(require('sdk/self').id) + "/preferences")`